# How to select html tr elements with a specific td class

Tags: selenium, class, web-scraping, xpath, html-table

I am using selenium to scrape a website, the website has a calendar and i want to get the days out of that calendar that have available times. I have inspected the calendar and found these elements

```
<table class="ui-datepicker-calendar">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col"><span title="Monday">Mån</span></th>
         <th scope="col"><span title="Tuesday">Tis</span></th>
         <th scope="col"><span title="Wednesday">Ons</span></th>
         <th scope="col"><span title="Thursday">Tor</span></th>
         <th scope="col"><span title="Friday">Fre</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Saturday">Lör</span></th>
         <th scope="col" class="ui-datepicker-week-end"><span title="Sunday">Sön</span></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">29</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">30</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">31</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">1</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">2</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">3</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">4</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">5</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">6</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">7</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">8</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">9</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">10</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">11</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" unavailable ui-datepicker-today" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-highlight" href="#">12</a></td>
         <td class=" available" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">13</a></td>
         <td class=" available" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">14</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">15</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">16</a></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">17</a></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">18</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">19</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">20</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">21</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">22</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">23</a></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">24</a></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">25</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">26</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">27</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">28</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">29</a></td>
         <td class=" unavailable" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="8" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default" href="#">30</a></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">1</span></td>
         <td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-other-month ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled unavailable"><span class="ui-state-default">2</span></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

as you can see the days that have times available have td class= " available" those are the days I want to save and keep in a list.

I have managed to get the day number printed out so I seem to have all the rows saved as elements since when I do

```py
avail = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"ui-datepicker-calendar")

for elem in avail:
    print(elem.text)
```

the output I get is 29,30,31,1,2,3,4...

How do I only save the rows that have td class= " available"?

Comment: Can you confirm the url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD**
Since the parent `td` class may contain additional class names we can use `contains` instead of `equals` and use `not` to exclude unavailable dates.  As following:

```py
avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//td[not(contains(@class,'unavailable'))]//a[@class='ui-state-default']")

for elem in avail:
    print(elem.text)
```

Comment: Hi i have edited my html code, so now you can see at the top that the table class is a ui-datepicker-calendar. Should I still use it or ui-state-default?

Comment: Thank you! It works! But i had to change 

`avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//tr[@class=' available']//a[@class='ui-state-default']")`

to 

`avail = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//td[@class=' available']//a[@class='ui-state-default']")`

Comment: In case you only want to select the available days you do not need that `ui-datepicker-calendar` but now I see no `available` class at all

Comment: Thank you for help, i have one small additional question.
Now I am getting the days that are available, but there first available day is not picked up since it looks like this 

`<td class=" available ui-datepicker-current-day" data-handler="selectDay" data-event="click" data-month="10" data-year="2022"><a class="ui-state-default ui-state-active" href="#">25</a></td>`

Is there a way to do a OR operation so it also picks this class up as an available day?

Comment: Sure. But maybe it will be better to ask it as a new question? each question here should be focused about 1 specific issue

Comment: Ah, sure, I will edit my answer

Comment: Now it should catch that issue. In case it still not - please let me know

Comment: I am getting all the dates now. I think since "available" is also contained in "unavailable"

Comment: Ah, makes sense. But we can use "not contains" `unavailable` right?

Comment: Now it works, I checked. Pay attention to `td` instead `tr`